# How to install Python 3.11 without sudo

Tags: python, linux, ssl, openssl

I'm using RHEL 7.9, and since Python relies on OpenSSL, I used this configuration command to build and install OpenSSL 1.1.1 from source (edit: I was using no-shared before):

```
./config --prefix=$HOME/.local --openssldir=$HOME/.local --libdir=lib shared zlib-dynamic
```

Then, I configured, built, and installed Python with this configuration:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations --prefix=$HOME/.localpython --with-openssl=$HOME/.local --with-openssl-rpath=auto
```

However, when I tried to install using pip, I get this message:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

No matter how I've installed OpenSSL and Python so far, Python still can't get the SSL module. What's the correct way to do this for OpenSSL 1.1.1 and Python 3.11?

Comment: no-shared. But python works only with shared

Comment: @eri The same thing happens when I use shared.

Comment: Maybe better copy system python with virtualenv?

Comment: @eri I've been doing this in a virtual environment in fact, but the same thing happens when I run pip with the venv deactivated as well.

Comment: So don't run pip without venv))

Comment: @eri As I said I ran it both inside and outside of a venv, and in both cases it failed.

Comment: Install the `openssl11-dev` (IIRC) package, then read this: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2416